# Sorting list by most matched listitems

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, sorting

I've got a single array that contains at **minimum 3**, at **maximum 5** arrays with objects. My goal is to append these objects in to lists, so my result will consist of 3, 4, or 5 lists. I'm trying to sort these list in a somewhat unconventional matter. I want to match the list items with **the position of the list items in the other lists**. I then want to put the **list item that has to most matches at the top**, and the ones with the **least matches at the bottem**. **The lists always contain 10 list items.**

So for instance, if "Item 3" is present in all five of the lists, "Item 3" gets moved to position 1 in the list for all the lists. If "Item 21" is present in three of the lists, and no other list item is present in more than three of the lists, "Item 21" gets moved to position 2 in all of the lists that contain "Item 21", and so on.

All list items are objects that can be matched via an `id`. My array could look like the following:

```
var listsToSort = [
  [
      {id: 1, name: 'Item 1'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'},
      {id: 7, name: 'Item 7'},
      {id: 8, name: 'Item 8'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Item 9'},
      {id: 11, name: 'Item 11'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Item 12'},
      {id: 16, name: 'Item 16'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Item 18'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Item 19'}
  ],
  [
      {id: 2, name: 'Item 2'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'},
      {id: 5, name: 'Item 5'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Item 12'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Item 14'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Item 15'},
      {id: 16, name: 'Item 16'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Item 18'},
      {id: 21, name: 'Item 21'},
      {id: 23, name: 'Item 23'}
  ],
  [
      {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Item 4'},
      {id: 5, name: 'Item 5'},
      {id: 6, name: 'Item 6'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Item 9'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Item 15'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Item 18'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Item 20'},
      {id: 21, name: 'Item 21'},
      {id: 22, name: 'Item 22'}
  ],
  [
      {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Item 9'},
      {id: 10, name: 'Item 10'},
      {id: 16, name: 'Item 16'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Item 18'},
      {id: 22, name: 'Item 22'},
      {id: 23, name: 'Item 23'},
      {id: 24, name: 'Item 24'},
      {id: 26, name: 'Item 26'},
      {id: 28, name: 'Item 28'}
  ],
  [
      {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Item 9'},
      {id: 11, name: 'Item 11'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Item 13'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Item 15'},
      {id: 16, name: 'Item 16'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Item 18'},
      {id: 25, name: 'Item 25'},
      {id: 27, name: 'Item 27'},
      {id: 29, name: 'Item 29'}
  ]
 ];
```

The result of this example array, when sorted, would look like the following: [image: example of sorted array]

Matched items receive a highlight class. "Gaps" in the list where no items are matched are filled with leftover list items that are not present in any of the other lists.

So to clarify, the matched items are placed at the some list positions across all of the lists. 
[image: example with legend]

How would I go about sorting the array in this matter?

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pafke/wg5L40c0/2/)**

Comment: how do you decide the order of the same count? it looks like random sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz The order is by most matches. The top item has five matches, so does the second, the third has 4 matches, the fourth has 4 matches, the fifth has 3 matches, and so on.

Comment: i have a problem, why is 16 first and not 9? both have a count of 4. –

Comment: @NinaScholz If the count is the same, the order does not matter. First hit is fine. The names are currently placeholder names. "Item 16" could as well be names "Lorum" and "Item 9" could be names "Ipsum". Sorry if this caused confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proposal uses a sort object and a reference to each single object for later reference for filling the arrays. This is done by using the sorted reference and it inserts then an object, if, or `null` if not.

To maintain the right order, not filled gaps are filled with the objects found at index 10 or greater. When all gaps above index 10 are filled, the length of the array is set to 10 and returned.

> ```
> raw array before moving values                                      moving values
>
>     0       1       2       3       4                                   4 
> ------  ------  ------  ------  ------                              ------
>     3       3       3       3       3 fixed part with values            3 
>    18      18      18      18      18                                  18
>     9    null       9       9       9                                   9
>    16      16    null      16      16                                  16
>  null      15      15    null      15                                  15
>  null       5       5    null    null                                null <--
>    11    null    null    null      11                                  11   |
>    12      12    null    null    null                                null <----
>  null      21      21    null    null                                null <------
>  null    null      22      22    null                                null <--------
>  ------------------------------------                               -----   | | | |
>  null      23    null      23    null variable part to fill above    null   | | | |
>     1    null    null    null    null                                null   | | | |
>  null       2    null    null    null                                null   | | | |
>  null    null       4    null    null                                null   | | | |
>  null    null       6    null    null                                null   | | | |
>     7    null    null    null    null                                null   | | | |
>     8    null    null    null    null                                null   | | | |
>  null    null    null      10    null                                null   | | | |
>  null    null    null    null      13                                  13 --- | | |
>  null      14    null    null    null                                null     | | |
>    19    null    null    null    null                                null     | | |
>  null    null      20    null    null                                null     | | |
>  null    null    null      24    null                                null     | | |
>  null    null    null    null      25                                  25 ----- | |
>  null    null    null      26    null                                null       | |
>  null    null    null    null      27                                  27-------- |
>  null    null    null      28    null                                null         |
>  null    null    null    null      29                                  29 ---------
> ```

This solution does not provide a stable result, because the sort oder is not stable with objects with the same count.

```js
var listsToSort = [[{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }, { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }, { id: 7, name: 'Item 7' }, { id: 8, name: 'Item 8' }, { id: 9, name: 'Item 9' }, { id: 11, name: 'Item 11' }, { id: 12, name: 'Item 12' }, { id: 16, name: 'Item 16' }, { id: 18, name: 'Item 18' }, { id: 19, name: 'Item 19' }], [{ id: 2, name: 'Item 2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }, { id: 5, name: 'Item 5' }, { id: 12, name: 'Item 12' }, { id: 14, name: 'Item 14' }, { id: 15, name: 'Item 15' }, { id: 16, name: 'Item 16' }, { id: 18, name: 'Item 18' }, { id: 21, name: 'Item 21' }, { id: 23, name: 'Item 23' }], [{ id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }, { id: 4, name: 'Item 4' }, { id: 5, name: 'Item 5' }, { id: 6, name: 'Item 6' }, { id: 9, name: 'Item 9' }, { id: 15, name: 'Item 15' }, { id: 18, name: 'Item 18' }, { id: 20, name: 'Item 20' }, { id: 21, name: 'Item 21' }, { id: 22, name: 'Item 22' }], [{ id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }, { id: 9, name: 'Item 9' }, { id: 10, name: 'Item 10' }, { id: 16, name: 'Item 16' }, { id: 18, name: 'Item 18' }, { id: 22, name: 'Item 22' }, { id: 23, name: 'Item 23' }, { id: 24, name: 'Item 24' }, { id: 26, name: 'Item 26' }, { id: 28, name: 'Item 28' }], [{ id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }, { id: 9, name: 'Item 9' }, { id: 11, name: 'Item 11' }, { id: 13, name: 'Item 13' }, { id: 15, name: 'Item 15' }, { id: 16, name: 'Item 16' }, { id: 18, name: 'Item 18' }, { id: 25, name: 'Item 25' }, { id: 27, name: 'Item 27' }, { id: 29, name: 'Item 29' }]],
    count = Object.create(null),
    countKeys,
    newList, 
    reference;

reference = listsToSort.map(function (a) {
    var o = Object.create(null);
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        count[b.id] = (count[b.id] || 0) + 1;
        o[b.id] = b;
    });
    return o;
});
countKeys = Object.keys(count);
countKeys.sort(function (a, b) { return count[b] - count[a]; });
newList = reference.map(function (a) {
    var temp = countKeys.map(function (k) {
            return a[k] || null;
        }),
        i = 0, j = 10;

    while (i < 10) {
        if (!temp[i]) {
            while (!temp[j]) {
                j++;
            }
            temp[i] = temp[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    temp.length = 10;
    return temp;
});

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Sorting alone is not enough, I want to put the list items **at the same position** as in the other lists. So "Gaps" have to be filled with a list item that is not matched in the other lists. By using your method, "Item 16" in the second list would be placed at position 3, while position 3 in the second list would be a "Gap" and thus be filled with an unmatched list item. And "Item 16" should be placed at the same heigh as "Item 16" in the the other lists

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your last paragraph: "This solution does not provide a stable result, because the sort oder is not stable with objects with the same count." At what use case would this break?

Comment: it measn simply for other systems with different sort algorithm, the result yould be different, but it still maintains the same position.